# Spyder 5.4 doesn't display results output automatically

Tags: python, spyder

I use Spyder 5.4 on macIOS. Previously, it used to display the results of any code automatically in the console. Now, this doesn't happen but the code run successfully. The results appear only if I wrap the code with `print()`. How can I get the results to appear automatically as before?

- Open Spyder and go to Tools -> Preferences.
- Navigate to IPython console -> Display.